# Updating a table using outputs and insert.da.cursor

Tags: arcpy

I have the following code however I need the outputs in a table which can be analysed further. How can I take the outputs from the code below and input into the table.
Ive used insert cursor but am getting the following error:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "< string >", line 11, in 
TypeError: value #1 - unsupported type: Result

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Zahir\AIS\Raw_AIS_Data\2013\Test\\"
gdblist = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
table = arcpy.CreateTable_management("D:\Zahir\AIS\Raw_AIS_Data\Test\\", "Table.dbf")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "Name", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "PosCount", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "TransCount", "SHORT")
fieldlist = ["Name", "PosCount", "TransCount"]

for g in gdblist:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(g)
    name  = desc.basename
    print name
    trans_table = "main.tblTransit"
    pos_table = "main.tblPositions"
    position_count = arcpy.GetCount_management(g + "\\" + pos_table)
    transits = arcpy.Frequency_analysis(g + "\\" + trans_table, "Trans_freq", "MMSI_ID")
    transit_count = arcpy.GetCount_management(transits)
    print g + " Unique Positions = " + str(position_count) + " and Vessel Count = " + str(transit_count)
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, fieldlist) as cursor:
        cursor.insertRow((name, position_count, transit_count))
```

Comment: Look at the Create Table tool to create a dbf file, you then need to add fields to it and within your loop you would have an insert cursor inserting the results into each row as you loop.

Comment: I think it may be time for you to [edit] your question and revise it heavily so that you can focus it on just the place that you are now stuck.  To me it is not clear what the results are that you want to export into a table nor what you mean by "average statistics".

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, I have edited the question now to just focus on the part I need

Comment: What are you expecting to see in your table?  Have you tried CreateTable then AddField to get the table schema right first?  Then you can use ArcPy.da.InsertCursor to populate it.

Comment: Ive updated the question having tried update.da.cursor, but the table isnt being updated with the information

Comment: fields must be accessed with their index, e.g. `row[0]` instead of `row.Name`

Comment: When you say fields are indexed ,is that within fieldlist or within the table?

Comment: Within `fieldlist`, since only these fields are accessible in your cursor.

Comment: Ive updated the question with your suggestion, but the table isnt updating with the outputs from the loop. There are no warning messages, so im not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: I try to understand the purpose of the script. With each loop over your gdb list, you're overwriting all row values in `table`. You should probably use an `InsertCursor`, since your table is initially empty.

Comment: Ive updated it using insert cursor but getting the following error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: value #1 - unsupported type: Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the insert cursor to work using arcpy.insertcursor...

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Zahir\AIS\Raw_AIS_Data\2013\Test\\"
gdblist = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
table = arcpy.CreateTable_management("D:\Zahir\AIS\Raw_AIS_Data\Test\\", "Table.dbf")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "Name", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "PosCount", "LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "TransCount", "LONG")
cursor = arcpy.insertcursor(table)

for g in gdblist:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(g)
    name  = desc.basename
    print name
    trans_table = "main.tblTransit"
    pos_table = "main.tblPositions"
    position_count = arcpy.GetCount_management(g + "\\" + pos_table)
    transits = arcpy.Frequency_analysis(g + "\\" + trans_table, "Trans_freq", "MMSI_ID")
    transit_count = arcpy.GetCount_management(transits)
    print g + " Unique Positions = " + str(position_count) + " and Vessel Count = " + str(transit_count)
    row = cursor.newRow()
    row.setValue("Name", name)
    row.setValue("PosCount", position_count)
    row.setValue("TransCount", transit_count)
    cursor.insertRow(row)

del cursor
del row
```